# Freeing const pointer after enabling extra extensions in Vulkan

Tags: c, vulkan

I have just began learning the Vulkan API and as a challenge to myself I wanted to create a function that could enable any specific extensions. This function enables required instance extensions as well as any extensions the programmer asks for. The function works fine but with how the Vulkan implementation specifies that extensions are stored in `VkInstanceCreateInfo` as a `const char* const*` it seems that I have to allocate and free memory of a const pointer which I have been told is code smell. Found below are the `EnableExtensions` function as well as some code around the caller of this function, error checking omitted for brevity. Additionally, the code below is using some pseudo-interface which abstracts some of the Vulkan-ness away from the code.

```
int EnableExtensions(VkInstanceCreateInfo* createInfo, const char** extraExt, uint32_t numExtraExt)
{
    uint32_t numRequired;
    const char** required = getInstanceExtensions(&numRequired);

    //the code smell I am talking about
    const char** used = malloc(sizeof *used * (numRequired+numExtraExt);

    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < numRequired; i++)
    {
        used[i] = required[i];
    }

    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < numExtraExt; i++)
    {
        used[numRequired + i] = extraExt[i];
    }

    populateCreateInfoStruct(createInfo, used, numRequired+numExtraExt);

    return VK_SUCCESS;
}
```

In main.c

```
//Initalization code above

VkInstance instance;
VkApplicationInfo appInfo;
populateAppInfoStruct(&appInfo);

VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo;
createInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;

const char* extra[4] = {"VK_EXT_one", "VK_EXT_two", "VK_EXT_three", "VK_EXT_four"};

EnableExtensions(&createInfo, extra, 4);

vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, NULL, &instance);

//Application code here

//I am worried about this
free((void*) createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames);
vkDestroyInstance(instance, NULL);
```

As you can see at the bottom of main.c I free the memory I allocated in `EnableExtensions` which I think I should do as to not cause a memory leak. However, if I remove the cast to void* then gcc complains. Is there any way around this issue or am I stuck doing something like this if I continue using C for this project?

Comment: What is the type of `createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames`? C allows any pointer type to be converted automatically to/from `void*` without requiring a cast. C++ requires the cast, though.

Comment: @Barmar it is of type `const char* const*`

Comment: Ah, it's warning about casting away const, right? Because the parameter to `free()` is declared `void *`, not `const void *`.

Comment: Yes that's exactly right

Comment: https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/217935-passing-const-void-free

Comment: Perhaps you are making your own trouble here.  Although it's not entirely clear, I get the impression that you are freeing this data in preparation for the program terminating.  You don't have to do that.  When the process terminates, the OS will reclaim all memory assigned to it, regardless of its allocation status.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I figure I am making my own trouble. Your assumption is right that I am freeing data in preparation to terminate. I also understand that it's not completely necessary because the OS will reclaim it all anyways. I am just doing it because I like to have all of my memory freed. It just seems like this is a case where this type of allocation and cleanup is more difficult than more common situations.

Comment: @Barmar Is it even possible to have a dynamic object of const effective type?